# Convert MS Office Document to XML

Tags: xml, ms-office, sax, apache-tika, docx4j

I am working on this project that requires extracting data from all sorts of document, and for this I need to convert the document to XML so that I can later parse it using SAX Parser. So, how do I get the XML equivalent of a ms office document?

Comment: If the document is saved with one of the newer formats (eg. `.docx` for Word) then it is already Zipped XML.

Comment: Which file formats are you working with? Something like `.doc` is quite different to something like `.xlsx`. Also, what kind of XML? HTML? Other?